# Можно ли сделать xor на xmm0 (не pxor)?

Tags: c, ассемблер, masm32, masm

Можно ли вместо `pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0` в ассемблерном коде использовать `xor %xmm0, %xmm0` и почему?

Comment: Нельзя, потому что инструкция xor не работает с этими регистрами.

Comment: А почему не работает?

Comment: Потому что так решили инженеры интел, когда придумывали инструкции.

Comment: xor работает только с обычными регистрами x86 (типа rax/eax/ax/al/ah). С регистрами [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_data) расширений работают свои отдельные инструкции.

Comment: С тем же успехом можно спросить, можно ли для регистров FPU использовать add вместо fadd? Нет, нельзя. Почему — потому что для работы с FPU нужно использовать отдельный набор команд.

Comment: А, собственно, с чего у вас возник такой вопрос? У вас есть какая-то задача, для которой `pxor` не подходит (например, хочется получить флаг ZF, если результат - ноль)? Или вы просто интересуетесь, почему похожая инструкция называется по другому?